# How is $\dfrac{A^2}{8\pi}$ is the energy per unit volume of light?

Tags: special-relativity

In his 1905 [paper](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf), under the section: 
**8. Transformation of the Energy of Light Rays. Theory of the Pressure of Radiation Exerted on Perfect Reflectors**, Einstein states:

> Since $\dfrac{A^2}{8\pi}$ equals the energy of light per unit of volume...

Where $A$ is the amplitude of electric or magnetic force(As defined by him in page 16 of the paper).

Einstein just direclty stated this result, but I cannot see why this relation is true or where it does come from?

Comment: Sorry, what is the amplitude of a force? Did you mean *magnitude*?

Comment: @Danu In page 16 of the paper Einstein writes: "We still have to find the amplitude of the waves, as it appears in the moving system. If we call the amplitude of the electric or magnetic force A or A′ respectively, accordingly as it is measured in the stationary system or in the moving system"

Answer (score 1):

The term is the energy density of a EM field in Gaussian units. See Marion classical electromagnetic radiation section 4.7 for details or Google poyntings theorem.

Comment: After some googling, I found that the magnitude of time-averaged ponyting vector which is the energy per unit area of a plane electromagnetic wave is $\epsilon_0 c/2 A^2$ which is $A^2/8\pi$ in planck units. However this is the enegy per unit area not volume. So can you help me with that?

Comment: I have provided a link too the relevant section in Marion (4.7). Hope it helps! https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9kKHPlcNm2kC&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=marion+4.7+classical+electromagnetic+radiation&source=bl&ots=pkOrqBIQS7&sig=XqV_NtcKrDLB4eeBzNShPiLH340&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBGoVChMIpNOG-bHyxwIVBAjbCh0npg39#v=onepage&q&f=false